# SciPy probplot TypeError: 'Text' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I keep getting the following error when trying to construct a SciPy probability plot

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deadrabbit_console_0-1.py", line 202, in <module>
    DRconsole().cmdloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cmd.py", line 142, in cmdloop
    stop = self.onecmd(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cmd.py", line 221, in onecmd
    return func(arg)
  File "deadrabbit_console_0-1.py", line 196, in do_analyze_run
    a.plot(targt_data)
  File "/home/baconwichsand/Documents/deadrabbit/branches/analysis.py", line 279, in plot
    self.draw(targt_data)
  File "/home/baconwichsand/Documents/deadrabbit/branches/analysis.py", line 186, in draw
    probplot(prob, self._timefrm[i])
  File "/home/baconwichsand/Documents/deadrabbit/branches/analysis.py", line 89, in probplot
    stats.probplot(data, sparams=params, plot=plot)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/morestats.py", line 355, in probplot
    plot.title('Probability Plot')
TypeError: 'Text' object is not callable
```

This is my `probplot` function, for plot I am passing a `pylab.subplot2grid` plot (working everywhere else)

```
    def probplot(plot, timeframe):
        """Probability plot given certain timeframe"""

        data = sample[np.where(sample[:, 4] == timeframe)][:, 5]
        mu = np.mean(data)
        sigma = np.std(data)
        alpha = stats.skew(data)
        x_plot = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), 1000)
        params = (mu, sigma, alpha)

        stats.probplot(data, sparams=params, plot=plot)
```

Comment: were you define `plot.title` ?

Comment: I don't...scipy is trying to do it for me. If I try to define it myself I still get the same error but instead of 'Probability Plot' is says whatever I defined

Comment: What version of scipy are you using?

Comment: currently using 0.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue in 0.10.1. Works after updating.

Comment: I'm using scipy 0.13.3 and the getting this same error.